# What do I need to add or rearrange so there is another decimal place?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in my first year of CS and we use Python3. I managed to code properly and submitted it into gradescope, but it was incorrect because one decimal was missing (the 4 at the end). My professor told me to rearrange the equation, so I tried swapping the numbers around, but it still didn't give me the answer I want.

I swapped the multiplied numbers with the one beside it, but it only threw off the number more.

```
import math
import stdio
import sys

theta = float(sys.argv[1])
n1 = float(sys.argv[2])
n2 = float(sys.argv[3])

theta1_rad = theta1*math.pi/180
theta2_rad = math.asin(n1*math.sin(theta1_rad)/n2)
theta2 = theta2_rad*180/math.pi

print(theta2)
```

When I plug in `$ python3 snell.py 58 1 1.52` into the terminal, I expect the output of `33.912513998258994`, but the actual output I get is `33.91251399825899`.

Comment: Your grading system is terrible if it's expecting an exact match out of a floating-point calculation. (There are limited, specific contexts where that can sometimes be reasonable, but a first-year CS student is not going to be working in those contexts.)

Comment: i used `print(f'{theta:.16f}')`. I get `...89871`

Comment: Just curious which Operating System are you using?

Comment: @PranavVoid I'm using the oracle virtual box on my macbook!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
import sys

theta = float(sys.argv[1])
n1 = float(sys.argv[2])
n2 = float(sys.argv[3])

theta1_rad = round(theta*math.pi/180,15)
theta2_rad = round(math.asin(n1*math.sin(theta1_rad)/n2),15)
theta2 = round(theta2_rad*180/math.pi,15)

print(theta2)
```

Try this hopefully it will work according to your expectation!

Comment: This is a late response, but it fixed my problem right away. Thank you so much!

Comment: happy to help you with your problem. can you mark is as right answer?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663292/9516410) answer in a similar question, try using **numpy.float128**. Or you could go for [Decimal datatype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)  as stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not OP, but I still get `...89871` even after using numpy.