# How to convert floats into double to stuct pack?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to pack a struct that looks like this on c++:

```
typedef struct {
    double    var1
    double    var2
} myType;
```

In my python script I have the user enter 2 inputs that I cast to a float.

```
var1 = float(input())
var2 = float(input())
payload = struct.pack("dd", var1, var2)
```

Now this won't work because I'm trying to send floats in as doubles.  Is there anyway to get this working?  I cannot change myType so that option is off the table.

Comment: Can you not cast to `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: Not in python no.  Doubles don't exist there.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need `typedef` there. Just do `struct myType { double var1; double var2; };` and it'll be `typedef`:ed automatically.

Comment: Btw, when you say "_send_", do you mean that you want to serialize the struct and send it over the network or to a file or similar?

Comment: You're already doing it. [Python `float` *is* `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663292/10077).

Comment: Fred, I just realized now that this was a dumb question.  Apparently you're right and packing with "ff" will do the trick.

Comment: No,  I think you still want `"dd"`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

Comment: Jeez seems like Im the big dumb dumb.  I swear using the "dd" was giving me an error but now it works :/

Comment: @topfoxrider: Don't be too hard on yourself. We've all been there.